# how to save data into database without redirecting to other page in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC. In my jsp page i have table which inline editable and with every table i have attached one button during edit (when you want to edit then just click on edit button in the dropdown, immediately that row will become editable and edit button will be visible beside that row) so when i will click it, immediately it should save the data of that row to database.

I can do that by providing a link (using  tag) with button so when i will click this link, it will match with @RequestMapping in the Controller and from there i will save the data of whole table into database. Now again i have to come back to my previous page so again it will load whole page from database which is very costly.

Can some help me so that only that row id should go to controller and from there it should save into database and i don't have to reload the page again.

Comment: can someone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should send your request via Ajax. The page will never reload, and you can choose to reload only a page segment. The easiest way is to use [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/), bind a method to your links, something like

```
$("a.saveToDB").click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    $.ajax({ 
      url: link.attr("href"), 
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(text) { 
        // show success message to the user
      }, 
      error: function(xhr) {
        // show error message to the user
     }});
    // prevent links default action
    return false;
});
```

The controller method can return a String, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String saveToDB() {
    // save to DB
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: from @RequestMapping method we have to send any jsp file. and if we do not want then it shows error. How?

Comment: download https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase it will be a valuable learning asset. The examples of what you need you'll find under Mapping tab and RequestMappingController

Comment: can we return string also? then why it showing error that .jsp file is not found

Comment: In your project how you have returned string in controller after mapping? And still it is working?